Bootstrap components don't appear as expected with React Bootstrap
I'm trying to learn bootstrap (currently using V5.3.3 if that helps, though it looks like I also have react-bootstrap V2.10.4, which is boostrap 5, it appears) but a lot of my code is giving me unexpected outputs.  I'm taking code from example pages and it's coming out a lot different.  For instance, I took some code from Bootstrap - Flex:
This is my code:
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import './App.css'

// Added for bootstrap, leaving this out seems to remove bootstrap formatting
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

// Will update if you manually add components
import { Table, Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <div className="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
        <div className="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
        <div className="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
        <div className="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
      </div>
      <div className="d-flex flex-row-reverse bd-highlight">
        <div className="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
        <div className="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
        <div className="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

This is what I'm expecting to see
This is what I'm actually seeing
I've been trying to resolve the issues with the element code itself but now it's starting to feel like I have some sort of understanding issue or issues with the way I'm implementing this?  I'm having a hard time understanding where the issue lies, much less how to resolve it.
EDIT: Maybe the issue is my form is using react-bootstrap that doesn't support the Flex form?  If that's the case, how do I update my form to use REGULAR bootstrap?  Or maybe I can't and react-bootstrap is my only option?  That might be my new issue . . .
Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

did you try including BS via CDN: docs example

also, BS site has custom css styles, so you shouldn't expect every code from there to look exactly the same on your site

does this Github issue describe your problem Output shown on documentation page of example of flex is different so, just use the current version

@traynor the issue from the github style wise is similar, my bigger issue is the alignment being all centered.  That said, I might have some other issues related to how I'm "containing" the components that stop me from seeing the alignment changes.  If that's the case, the style issue might be kicking in.  Going to check out those other links you sent and see what I can get working, see if I can figure out what the root cause is.  Thanks for the suggestions!
